# How to disable System shortcut on MAC by AppleScript

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, applescript

I'm making a exam console app for Mac. I used ElectronJS and when user enter the exam room, this app will be set to `kiosk` mode.

But only some shortcuts such as **CMD+tab** were disabled.
Other shortcut such as **F12**, **CMD+shift+4**, **CMD+F5** weren't disabled.

I am looking for the methodology to disable system shortcut during examination.

If AppleScript will touch this problem, it will be great help for me.